# Privacy policy on Facebook tab

Tags: facebook, tabs, privacy-policy

I received an e-mail from Facebook that i need to include a privacy policy in my Facebook tab. I thought privacy policy's were only needed in Facebook Apps.

Were can i find an example of a privacy policy?

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, the reason for Facebook's strict requirements are mostly because of them wanting to demonstrate that they do everything to educate their users "we told the user to have a privacy policy". Therefore you receiving that email may not necessarily be related to you doing anything related to privacy.

In theory it's still possible to gather data from a tab/page with input forms.

iubenda has been specialising in this kind of problem with a dedicated privacy policy generator for Facebook apps and a hosting service for privacy policies built in: http://iubenda.com/facebook/

**There's also a basic free version** to be had for the general privacy policy here http://iubenda.com (edit: I haven't pointed out that the free version only works for web policies, as commented on by one user)

(disclosure: I work with the iubenda team to keep this being the best possible tool out there)

Comment: Can't seem to find the basic free version. As soon as I click the "next" button on the first tab, I'm presented with purchase options.

Comment: I tried, and iubenda basic free version is terrible, since you must pay to add permissions such as `user_about_me`.

Comment: there are limits to the basic online web version, mostly those limits are related to e-commerce. That's how we make sure that you get a quality product, samwize, and not merely a hobby :)

Comment: it's not free for iOS apps.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommending using  http://termsfeed.com/free/privacy-policy-generator
in preference to http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php since the latter has a terms of use that includes:

*Permission is granted ... for the sole purpose of placing an order with FreePrivacyPolicy.com or purchasing FreePrivacyPolicy.com products. Any other use, ... is strictly prohibited, unless authorized by FreePrivacyPolicy.com.*

Sorry I couldn't send a link to their terms of use, it appeared as a javascript popup, at the end of their wizard questionaire.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.generateprivacypolicy.com/
I use this to create a privacy policy for just several seconds.

Comment: Do you know why tabs need to have a privacy policy? I don't see them on the tab, seems a bit useless.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same mail aswell and I don't really understand why. I used this one to create it: http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you gather any data (forms, etc.) from that particular tab? They may simply have changed the requirements.

You should try to re-write any privacy policy depending the type of data you gather (or not).

You can also use the following from Termsfeed (free generator): http://termsfeed.com/free/privacy-policy-generator

Answer (score 0):

Simple Facebook features like Page Plugin (which used to be called Tabs) do not require a Privacy Policy or TOS. The essential fact I found when when trying to work this out was in the FAQ. You don't need an "app," or even a developer account. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs says it. That means you don't need an app Privacy Policy or TOS.

A problem arises when you are logged in as a developer and click "Get code" in the wizard at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/. It gives you the developer version of the javascript SDK. It has the line `js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=...&autoLogAppEvents=1'`, with your most recent appId filled in.

The workaround is to log out of Facebook before using the wizard. Then you will get the correct code which does not require Privacy/TOS: `js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12'`.

Answer (score -1):

I found an excellent one (which even generates and hosts your privacy policy) [here](http://privacychoice.org/policymaker) by [privatychoice.org](http://www.privacychoice.org/faq#mission)

Comment: Just to prevent others from going to the link: it belongs to a different company now